# How can I convert characters into numerical value and average them based on a categorical column?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is sample data:

```
project = c("ProjA", "ProjA", "ProjB", "ProjB","ProjC", "ProjC")
Q1 = c("Unlikely", "Very likely", "Likely","Unlikely", "Very likely", "Likely" )
Q2 = c("Very easy", "Easy", "Difficult", "Neutral","Very easy", "Easy")

masterdf = data.frame(project, Q1,Q2)
```

My goal is to convert the Q1 and Q2 into percentages, and then average them based on the project they're in. This way, we can find the average performance of each project in each question.

Something I've tried is:

```
value = c("Likely", "Very likely")
Q1 = masterdf %>% count(Q1) %>% arrange(desc(n))
Q1 = Q1 %>% mutate(pct = Q1$n/sum(Q1$n) *100) %>% 
  filter(Q1 %in% value)
```

But it doesn't work, plus it doesn't relate back to what Project it belongs to. The values are Top 2 box, so Very Likely, Likely, Easy, and Very Easy would be successes. Ideally, what I would like is a table that looks like this:

| Project | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ProjA | 50% | 47% |
| ProjB | 50% | 47% |
| ProjC | 50% | 47% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
masterdf %>% 
  # Make a tidy dataset
  pivot_longer(
    cols=starts_with("Q"), 
    names_to="Question", 
    values_to="Answer"
  ) %>% 
  # Convert from categorical to binary
  mutate(Success=Answer %in% c("Very Likely", "Likely", "Easy", "Very Easy")) %>% 
  # Calculate success rates by project and question
  group_by(project, Question) %>% 
  summarise(Rate=100*sum(Success)/n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
  # Transpose for pressentation
  pivot_wider(
    names_from=Question,
    values_from=Rate
  )
```

Gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  project    Q1    Q2
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 ProjA       0    50
2 ProjB      50     0
3 ProjC      50    50
```

Some of the advantages of using [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data is that the code is robust with respect to changes in the numbers and labels of projects and the number of questions and responses.  It also fits better with tidyverse verbs as they are designed for tidy data.